# Inserting context after an element in css

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <style>
        div label:last-child:after {
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            background: #8F8B8B;
            height: 5px;
            margin-left:1%;
         }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
       <input type="radio" id="thumbnails" name="view" />
       <label for="thumbnails"></label>
       <label for="thumbnails"></label>
       <ul></ul>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

But for some reason it does not enter anything before the ul.

If i do this:

```
div ul:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background: #8F8B8B;
  height: 5px;
  margin-left:1%;
}
```

works great, but i do not want this.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: And it's far more easy to copy/paste some text than to retype your code.

Comment: _"it does not enter nothing"_ So it enters something? And why don't you want the code you shared that "works great"?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: `ul:before` "works great, but i do not want this."  Why not?

Comment: Inserts the content inside the ul for some reason and i want it out

Comment: your label is not the `:last-child` in that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because the `last-child` of the `div` is actually the `<ul>`

Try `label:last-of-type:after`

Comment: ohh love it, css always surprises with funky new selectors